# Jmagick error : magick.MagickException: No image to scale

Tags: java, ubuntu, imagemagick, jmagick

I am trying to integrate jmagick over ImageMagick, so I have installed Image magick 6.4.0 and JMagick 6.4.0 Q16 on my Ubuntu 11.10
I tried the following piece of code on Eclipse to test jmagick integration :

```
try{
ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo("myPic.jpg");
MagickImage image = new MagickImage();
MagickImage bigger = image.scaleImage(1200, 900);
bigger.setFileName("bigger.jpg");
bigger.writeImage(info);
} catch (MagickException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When running a simple main class, I get the following exception :

```
magick.MagickException: No image to scale
at magick.MagickImage.scaleImage(Native Mehtod)
at comcom.myCompany.image.ImageTest.main(ImageTest.java:20)
```

Did anyone face/solve the same problem?

Comment: I discovered that the error was due to the "jpg" image format, I tried the same code with a "png" image, and all worked pefectly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution might be to verify if image magick is configured to work with all needed image format.. To verify that, tap the following command and seach for the keyword **DELEGATES** for the file extensions ImageMagick is configured to use :

```
convert -list configure
```

If you don't have the required library installed, then you need to download it from the image magick delegates special page which you can find here : http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/

Once the delegate library downloaded, you need to unzip it and install it fowllowing these instrcutions :

```
tar xzvf jpegsrc.v7.tar.gz
 cd jpegsrc/
 ./configure
 sudo make
 sudo make install
 make clean
```

Next, you nedd to reconfigure and reinstall imagemagick from the source directory of image magick which you need to locate :

```
./configure
 sudo make
 sudo make install
```

Now retry to see if image magick handles your image format